# I got error while simulate code written in PROMELA

Tags: promela

I am using ispin and got an error stating spin: trails end after 10 steps and transition fail.

How can I prevent this error from happening?

Comment: Please provide more detail, like what the exact error is and what you have tried.

Comment: Include the code that fails by editing your question. I have not seen [anyone](http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/104307/anyone) on this site, so the answer to your original question was probably "No she can't". Yes/no answerable questions (easily checked) are seldom good questions here.

Answer (score 0):

You prevent the error from happening in one of two ways:

1. fix your Promela model - you have a bug in your Promela that needs to be removed
2. you've found an error in the *system that you are modeling*.  Congratulations.  You now report the error to the person in charge of the s*ystem that you are modeling*.

In practice, when you have a trail indicating an error, you next perform

```
spin -p -t <name of the model>.pml
```

which will print out the step by step model executions that lead to the error.  You scour them to confirm that they are correct - if so, see #2 above; if not correct, see #1.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it is fixed after putting `-DVECTORSZ` :

[image: compile-option]

in the *advanced parameters settings window* of *verification* tab.I have also increased the physical memory to 2048.